# check log script with present date

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple check code which reads the log filename (after backup) from a given directory and gives information if log with present date was created or if it wasn't. Code should and with exit = 0 (TRUE) or exit = 2 (FALSE). Log is constructed from name and current date eg. log_2018_08_22)
I`m getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'. Please, any one may help me with it? Im not really familiar with coding yet :\

`import datetime
 import pathlib
 import sys
 import os`

`os.path.abspath("C:\Test")`
`file = "backup_{:%Y_%m_%d}.log"`
`path = file.format(datetime.datetime.now())`

`if file.exists():
    print("File exist")
    sys.exit(0);
else:
    print("File not exist")
    sys.exit(2);`

Answer (score 0):

When you put in the line:

```
file = "backup_{:%Y_%m_%d}.log"
```

you defined `file` as a string. You can create a file-like object by using python's [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method. I would try something like the following:

```
filename = "backup_{:%Y_%m_%d}.log".format(datetime.datetime.now())
file = open(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that did the trick but now i`m getting strange error. **file = open(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'backup_2018_08_22.log'**
but i have file backup_2018_08_22.log in C:\Test... 
Below is the code. One more question this script should be working on Ubuntu and there paths are slighty different.

`#!/usr/bin/python
  import datetime
  import sys
  import os`

`os.path.abspath("C:\Test")
filename = "backup_{:%Y_%m_%d}.log".format(datetime.datetime.now())
file = open(filename)`

`if file.exists():
    print("File exist")
    sys.exit(0);
else:
    print("File not exist")
    sys.exit(2);`

Answer (score 0):

Ive modified the script and now its working. Case closed :)

`#!/usr/bin/python
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import datetime`
`my_file = Path("C:/Test/backup_{:%Y_%m_%d}.log".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
if my_file.is_file():
    print("Found it")
    sys.exit(0)`

`else:
    print("Cant find it")

    sys.exit(2)`